# Query from 500 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-5.5

I want to get query from 500 tables with `Laravel`.
The columns ​​of all tables are the same and I want to get the last row of each table with a query.
I was looking for a solution, but I did not get a good result.
In the end, I had to use the solution below

```
$data1 : DB::table('table1')->orderby('id','desc')->first();
$data2 : DB::table('table2')->orderby('id','desc')->first();
$data3 : DB::table('table3')->orderby('id','desc')->first();
.
.
.
$data500 : DB::table('table500')->orderby('id','desc')->first();
```

And for each of the tables I have to create a model.
Thank you for your guidance

Comment: "The values ​​of all tables are the same" mean the same columns?

Comment: This smells like bad database design. 500 tables with the same columns?

Comment: This is why you should design your database table structures and relations properly and sensibly..... 500 identical tables is simply bad design; now you're beginning to learn why

Comment: yes my mean is columns.tnx i edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can make one big query becouse 500 separate query to the database it is not a good idea and 500 object istances can produce a memory limit error, so use an array of rows against one object for one query.

The PHP script can be presented as follows:

```
<?php

for ($i = 1; $i <= 500; $i++){
    $sql[] = "SELECT 'table{$i}' AS tableName, t{$i}.* FROM table{$i} AS t{$i} WHERE t{$i}.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table{$i})";
}

$query = implode(" UNION ALL ", $sql);

//get array instead objects
$result = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (array) $value;
}, DB::select($query));


?>
```

And I think you can not have 500 model classes to represent the same thing. 
So in any case you should review the structure.

**[Edit]**

You can consider constructing a model class that can change table based on a parameter that passes when instantiating the object extending the constructor.
Like this: (just an idea)

```
<?php 

class Table extends Model
{
    public function __construct($tableNum = '1', array $attributes = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($attributes);

        $this->table = $tableNum;
    }    
}

$model= new Table('500'); //extended constructor accept the param and set table
$model->getTable(); //return table500

?>
```

Comment: tnx @alvarofvr , Your solution was close to the answer.